# Is a user's Steam Inventory the same across computers?

Tags: steam

Is the Steam inventory on two different computers, but the same Steam account the same?
For example, same guns on CS:GO, even if these are two different computers, but with the same account?

Comment: This is the whole point of Steam.

Comment: Why shouldn't it?

Answer (score 30):

Yes. The inventories are tied to the *Steam account*, not the computer.

*However*, keep in mind that if you're trying to "share" your account with somebody... well, you shouldn't. It's against Steam's TOS and can create a lot of problems if you're trying to do things on both computers simultaneously.

But if it's just you, and you're using Steam on two different computers (at different times), your Steam inventory is the same on both computers. Get a new gun on one and you can use it later on the other.

Comment: If you do want to share accounts with someone though, Steam actually allows you to share your library with a friend (there's a limit on how many), but it allows someone else to play anything in your library without affect any of your save data (you'll have different guns in CS:GO).

Comment: "However, keep in mind that if you're trying to "share" your account with somebody... well, you shouldn't. "  This isn't exactly true. You are allowed to share your library with a few people using Family Sharing, but that does not share your save data. It's intended for family members and there are restrictions.

Comment: @coteyr actually it STILL is true. DJ here meant "share your account credentials so others can log into your account on other computers" Wherehas family sharing, once past the initial "I need to log in from this computer", doesn't require the sharee to enter the sharer's credentials.

Comment: @coteyr Sharing your library is not the same thing as sharing your _account_.

Comment: This is not entirely true but close enough. Free games need to be individually added to one's local library, so one might have more games in their steam library in computer A than computer B since they added more free games in A.

Comment: For the commenters: The asker wanted to know about Steam inventory. This is trading cards, TF2 hats, CSGO gun skins, giftable games, etc. Not Steam games library. The two are different. This question has nothing to do with the game library.

Comment: some content from these comments should probably be added to the answer itself to prevent confusion

Answer (score 3):

To add on to what @DJ Pirtu said your game library is not always the same across computers. This is because free games only show up in it if they are installed and so on what PC you may have 9 games whereas another 10.

I know this is about steam inventories but libraries are very closely tied onto that.

Comment: The asker wanted to know about Steam inventory. This is trading cards, TF2 hats, CSGO gun skins, giftable games, etc. Not Steam games library. The two are different.

Comment: @BradMetcalf I know which is why I pointed that out in my answer. However whenever I think of inventory Games also springs to mind and was the reason I clicked on the question, therefore I answered for other people making the same mistake as I did.

Answer (score 1):

Every aspect of your Steam Account is linked to the *account* and not the *computer*.
With this said wherever *computer* you are using, as long as you are *logged in*, you will have everything that you have in other *computers* that you used. You will have the same games (of course you need to download them in the different computers), the same saves, (Saved in the SteamCloud. If your local saves and your SteamCloud saves are not the same, Steam will ask you if you want to download the SteamCloud saves to your Local saves.), the same inventory (collection cards, game weapons...), etc...

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

**Source:** I change hardware components *and/or* format my computer almost monthly, and everything is still there.

Comment: Windows? I'm guessing Windows. I'm sorry about the formatting monthly...

Comment: @ColeBusby Why sorry? I do it voluntarily. I have the process (almost) completely automated. It takes about 20 minutes the OS installing (yep, Windows 10. Sometimes 8.1)  and ~40 minutes the installation of basic programs (which includes Steam). Unmanned. 

All my videos, documents (and, of course, Steam library) are in a different drive :)

Comment: @DanielParejoMuñoz cause, I'd much rather run linux on my main machine and when I want to game use a single windows install that gets a game. Aside from that, an hour every month to redeploy my system each month is an hour I can spend elsewhere. There's plenty of utilities to make my system "Like New" without the unneeded re-install. Maybe @vianna77 would agree in my question as to `WHY?`.

Comment: @vianna77 the list of poor ports are staggering. but I still enjoy the games I play. Linux is coming a long way. You would be **surprised**

Comment: @ColeBusby "Unmanned" means I actually expend that hour doing other stuff. About OSs Linux is great, I actually have a Linux installation in another drive for when I need it (and I do), but I like Windows, I'm a Windows developer (also was a MSP) and... I just like it. Even if you dislike it, I like it. Can we agree that each of us like a different thing? :) 
As for `WHY?`: I like clean installations. Like new clothes, they feel fresh and it's as good as any other thing to do a Sunday morning while I have breakfast and watch cartoons :)

Comment: @ColeBusby As for "Like New" tools: I'm guessing you refer to imaging. Yeah, imaging is great, but I don't like it for my specific use case. I prefer it fresh. Also, since nowadays all your configuration is linked to your online accoung (google, steam, microsoft... hell, they even keep my desktop background) everything is back in place very quickly ^^

Comment: Yeah, The more I thought about it, Windows 10 does a lot of this hard part for you